# How to remake componentDidMount to useEffect in my case?

Tags: reactjs

I have this class component:

```
class App extends React.Component {

       state = {data: []};

    async componentDidMount() {
         try {
            const res = await apiHelpFunction('/...', {
              method:'GET'
            });
             this.setState({data:res.data});
            } catch(e) { 
                console.error(e);
            } 
    };

    render(){
      return (
        <div>
           <Table dataAttribute = {this.state.data}/>
        </div>
    )}}
```

But I need functional component. And I try to remake this component into functional:

```
const App = () => {

      const [data, setData] = useState([]);


    //.... here should be useEffect with a request to the server


    render(){
      return (
        <div>
           <Table dataAttribute = {data} />
        </div>
    )}}
```

But I dont uderstand useEffect and how remake `componentDidMount` into `useEffect`. Please help me.

Comment: https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **useEffect** as componentDidMount by **providing function as arguments as first parameter and empty array ([]) in second arguments** .

Simply if you give no second argument in useEffect it will execute each time when your component get updated or mount . But if you provide empty array as second argument in useEffect then it will only execute at the time of component mount .

Their are many more use cases of useEffect , for better understanding refer https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

Refer below code

```
const App = () => {

      const [data, setData] = useState([]);


    useEffect(()=>{
      apiHelpFunction('/...', {
              method:'GET'
            }).then(res=>setData(res.data)).catch(e=>console.error(e));
  },[]);



      return (
        <div>
           <Table dataAttribute = {data} />
        </div>
    )}
```

**By using Async await :**

```
const App = () => {

      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      async function handleDataUpdate() {
         try {
            const res = await apiHelpFunction('/...', {
              method:'GET'
            });
             setData(res.data);
            } catch(e) { 
                console.error(e);
            } 
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
      handleDataUpdate();
  },[]);



      return (
        <div>
           <Table dataAttribute = {data} />
        </div>
    )}
```

Comment: Error:
``` Line 17:25:  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function```
in line: ```const res = await apiHelpFunction('/...', { ```

Comment: My bad,  you can't use useEffect first argument as async. I have changed code and used **then** instead. If you still want to use await then you can wrap you API code in another async function and then call in useEffect .

Comment: Now error: http://i.piccy.info/i9/3f58dd4df6051d4a658bc73dd2a7b8c5/1587645253/10896/1372209/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: @bytor , change async  handleDataUpdate()  to async function handleDataUpdate()  in function definition . I have updated code again.

Comment: http://i.piccy.info/i9/fd056a3ab9794319f95e571510cc7e89/1587645688/12256/1372209/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: @bytor,  updated code again , render function in not needed in functional components. Just return without render.

Comment: change **setData({data:res.data})** to **setData(res.data)** as you have to pass set array . If it still give same error then put console.log(res.data) to see the data of API.
I have updated the code.

Comment: thanks, it works. And what variant would you recommend to use in useEffect? async-await or then-catch?

Comment: @bytor, both async-await or then-catch are fine , use anyone as per your comfort. But there is one issue which you can face in future by making ajax call in componentDidMount or useEffect .**Assume you made ajax call and before getting ajax response your component's get unmounted and component unmount your ajax return response then it can cause error , this condition is called race condition.** To avoid race condition refer https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326

Comment: Apology @bytor, but I am not available in any of the other platform . I will try my best to help you on stack overflow .

Answer (score 0):

```js
const App = () => {

      const [data, setData] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
            apiHelpFunction('/...', {
              method:'GET'
             }).then(res => setData(res.data)).catch(console.error);


      },[])



    render(){
      return (
        <div>
           <Table dataAttribute = {data} />
        </div>
    )}}
```